# Get mean value avoiding nan using numpy in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to calculate mean value of an array (A) avoiding nan?

```
import numpy as np 
A = [5    nan    nan    nan    nan  10]
M = np.mean(A[A!=nan]) does not work
Any idea?
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`numpy.isnan`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> A = np.array([5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10])
>>> np.isnan(A)
array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> ~np.isnan(A)
array([ True, False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> A[~np.isnan(A)]
array([  5.,  10.])
>>> A[~np.isnan(A)].mean()
7.5
```

because you cannot compare `nan` with `nan`:

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
>>> np.nan != np.nan
True
>>> np.isnan(np.nan)
True
```

Answer (score 36):

An other possibility is the following:

```
import numpy
from scipy.stats import nanmean # nanmedian exists too, if you need it
A = numpy.array([5, numpy.nan, numpy.nan, numpy.nan, numpy.nan, 10])
print nanmean(A) # gives 7.5 as expected
```

i guess this looks more elegant (and readable) than the other solution already given

edit: apparently (@Jaime) reports that this functionality already exists directly in the latest `numpy` (1.8) as well, so no need to `import scipy.stats` anymore if you have that version of `numpy`:

```
import numpy
A = numpy.array([5, numpy.nan, numpy.nan, numpy.nan, numpy.nan, 10])
print numpy.nanmean(A)
```

the first solution works also for people who dont have the latest version of `numpy` (like me)

Comment: Numpy 1.8 has its own `nanmean` function, so you don't even need to import scipy.

Comment: @Jaime. You could post as an answer in the original question for future reference...

Comment: `scipy.stats.nanmean` and `scipy.stats.nanmedian` are now deprecated in favor of the `numpy` functions