# how to calculate geomatic average value with nans?

Tags: python, nan, geometric-mean

I would like to calculate the geometric mean of some data (including NaN), how can I do it?

I know how to calculate the mean value with NaNs, we can use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
M = np.nanmean(data, axis=2).
```

So how to do it with geomean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852586/get-mean-value-avoiding-nan-using-numpy-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480694/numpy-calculate-averages-with-nans-removed for a more efficient and slightly longer version, but replace `mean` with `geomean`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the identity (I only found it in the [german Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrisches_Mittel#Eigenschaften) but there are probably other sources as well):

[image]

This identity can be constructed using the "logarithm rules" on the normal definition of the geometric mean:

[image]

The base `a` can be chosen arbitarly, so you could use `np.log` (and `np.exp` as inverse operation):

```
import numpy as np

def nangmean(arr, axis=None):
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    inverse_valids = 1. / np.sum(~np.isnan(arr), axis=axis)  # could be a problem for all-nan-axis
    rhs = inverse_valids * np.nansum(np.log(arr), axis=axis)
    return np.exp(rhs)
```

And it seems to work:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, np.nan, 3], [np.nan, 2, np.nan]]

>>> nangmean(l)  
1.8171205928321397

>>> nangmean(l, axis=1)  
array([ 1.81712059,  1.73205081,  2.        ])

>>> nangmean(l, axis=0)  
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
```

---

In NumPy 1.10 also [`np.nanprod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanprod.html#numpy-nanprod) was added, so you could also use the normal definition:

```
import numpy as np

def nangmean(arr, axis=None):
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    valids = np.sum(~np.isnan(arr), axis=axis)
    prod = np.nanprod(arr, axis=axis)
    return np.power(prod, 1. / valids)
```